# React.useEffect does not cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events, use-effect

I have a custom react hook for detecting an outside click.

```js
function useOutsideClick(ref, onOutsideClick) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = event => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains?.(event.target)) {
        onOutsideClick(event);
      }
    }
    console.log('mounted');
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
      console.log('unmounted');
    }
  }, [onOutsideClick])
}
```

And here is what I see in the console.

```
mounted

mounted
unmounted

mounted
unmounted

...
```

As a result, I have two event listeners instead of one, because one of them not cleans up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you produce minimal reproducible example, maybe via codesandbox?

Comment: Did you use a hook inside a nested function? Try reading this first, and make sure you understand how hooks work. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Can you show your `onClick` function ?

Comment: Use a memozed function as event handler, it seems evrytime you are creating new function when hthe useEffect runs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was my bad. Everything is working fine. The thing is I have another component in the root of the page that unmounts only on leaving. So, the output is

```
mounted

mounted
unmounted

mounted
unmounted

...

unmounted
```